# Run Xvfb and bin/bash in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, xvfb

I have a docker container that uses as an entrypoint /bin/bash.
Once in the container, I can start xvfb in this way:

`Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render -noreset >> xsession.log 2>&1 &`

However, I would like this command to be performed in the Dockerfile, and *then* entering the container. I would like to use /bin/bash interactively.
I have tried several solution but nothing seems to work.

What I have tried:

runxvfb.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo try
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render -noreset >> xsession.log 2>&1 &
```

In the Dockerfile

```
ADD runxvfb.sh /runxvfb.sh
RUN chmod a+x /runxvfb.sh
CMD ["/runxvfb.sh; bin/bash"]
```

and several combination of this approach, but it doesn't seem to work. Once inside the container, `ps` shows that there is no xvfb daemon running.

Comment: that won't leave the interactive bash open - changed my question to make it clear I want to end up in /bin/bash

Comment: That also doesn't seem to work. My runxvfb.sh file is
#!/bin/sh
echo try
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render -noreset >> xsession.log 2>&1 &


I get "try" but the docker container gets closed after that (see updated question)

Comment: You can't launch background processes in a Dockerfile; the Docker image only contains the filesystem and not any running processes.  A virtual machine (with an X server, full init system, standard Linux desktop, and either an ssh daemon or a graphical console) might match this use case better.